# How to add text from one JTextField to another by pressing a JButton

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, textfield

I am creating a applet in java where the user enters some data into four different four different text fields, clicks a button, and the data is taken from those fields and stored in a text field next to it.

I have a button made, and it implements ActionListener, just not sure how to get the text from the four fields into the one field together.

Comment: `toTextField.setText(fromTextField.getText() + ...);` - Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: `textfield1.getText` and `textfield5.setText` in actionPerformed method of button's action even listener

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
tf1.setText(tf2.getText());
```

OR When you want to merge values from all textfields into one.

```
tf1.setText(tf1.getText() + tf2.getText() + tf3.getText() + tf4.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

> just not sure how to get the text from the four fields into the one field together.

JTextField has a `getText()` method. So you would invoke that method on the 4 different text field to get the String value from each text field.

JTextField also has a `setText()` method. So you would combine the 4 strings into one and set the text of the 5th text field.